How to convert grViz() output to the native DiagrammeR graph format?
As far as I understand, the DiagrammeR package's native format is dgr_graph. But when I construct the graph with grViz() function, I don't get this object:
library(DiagrammeR)
g <- grViz("digraph 'foodweb' {\n  \"h()\" -> { \"f()\", \"g()\" }\n  \"f()\"\n  \"g()\" -> { \"f()\" }\n}")
print(g) # renders beautiful graph
class(g) 
# [1] "grViz"      "htmlwidget"

How do I convert this object to the dgr_graph, so I can further use it with the DiagrammeR package? (My end goal is to export the rendered graph, which is shown in the html browser, into some other format, where I can move around the nodes and have the arrows move automatically with them.)
Note: this particular graph is just an example, I work with much larger graphs, in particular, function call graphs, produced by R package foodwebr, which calls DiagrammeR::grViz(). This is why I am interested how to work with the grViz() graph format.
